# How to take backup of Windows VSS store?

Tags: windows, backup, image, vss

Is it possible to take a backup or image of the shadow store created by the `Windows Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS)`?

Would `Windows Backup` include this data when doing a backup?

Comment: Backups of VSS.. Very meta.

Comment: The VSS "Store" by default is within the same file system as the files that are being shadowed; like a snapshot function of NTFS. They aren't actually copied anywhere (normally) unless the file is changed after the shadow is taken.

Comment: Are you asking this in hopes of a full restore having access to "previous versions"?  If so, good question.

Answer (score -2):

There's actually no reason to back up this store. All VSS does is make a copy of your drive (well, commonly-used files) that is actually used by Windows Backup and other backup tools.

Comment: Sure there is a reason.  Lets say I was transitioning to a new file and I wanted the 'Previous Versions' tab to keep working for my users.

Comment: Makes sense. In that case an image backup would be more appropriate because of the way VSS handles things.

Comment: @NathanC: how can I create an image backup of just one folder?

Comment: @CJ7 You can't. Image backup is the entire server.